# list all email matching filter on one page?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I do a search, and get all the emails appear. Lots of messages match. I want to get rid of all the ones I see but see the subject first.

But it only shows me 20. I click the checkbox that selects them all and click trash. And it removes them but then another 20 appear.

I went to settings and changed it from whatever it was at, to display 100.  But it still says

[image]

I click "select all conversations that match this search" it says all are selected, I click trash. It says bulk deletion, I do OK. But there are still more left. It looks like it only deleted the 20.

I'd like to at least delete 100 at a time. Preferably get many more listed on one page. So I can see the subjects of what i'm deleting and delete lots at a time.  At worst i'd just want to delete them all without seeing the subjects of them all. But this deleting 20 at a time is terrible.

**Added-**

My Email when not doing a search, shows as 100. I get 100 listed.

But when doing a search, then it only shows 20 at a time

i.e.

This is what it says for my search

[image]

This is what it says  when not doing a search. so if I just click on inbox 
[image]

Comment: @pnuts I actually wrote "I went to settings and changed it from whatever it was at, to display 100. But it still says..all 20" So yeah, there, it says 100,  perhaps you didn't see that. And anyhow now i've added more pics. Do you not use gmail then? If you used gmail then you could see if you get this

Comment: @pnuts It needn't involve deletion. Read my post in particular after where I wrote 'added', it involves doing a search where there are more than 20 results, and seeing the count it gives of how many emails it is displaying for a search (you can contrast that with the count with regular email non-searched) e.g. in the pic I give it says 1-20 of 47. (for the search)